# how to remove Unexpected request: GET data.json?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to use  **$httpBackend** to test my $http request ..i AM getting

this error

```
Unexpected request: GET data.json
No more request expected
```

here is my testing code

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller,appfactory,_$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();  
    $httpBackend=_$httpBackend_;
     ctrl = $controller('cntrl', {$scope: $scope});
     fac=appfactory;
    modeSpy= spyOn(fac, 'mode').and.returnValue('a');

}));



  it('test true value',function(){
    expect(true).toBeTruthy()
  })

   it('check message value',function(){
     $scope.toggle();
   expect($scope.message).toEqual('naveen')
  })

   it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    //expect(fac.setValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
    var response=[{"name":"naveen"},{"name":"parveen"}]
    $httpBackend.expectGET('data.json').respond(response);
     $scope.getData();
     $httpBackend.flush();

     expect($scope.data[0].name).toEqual('naveen')
  });
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/zdfYdtWbnQz22nEbl6V8?p=preview

**Solution to remove this error**

```
I have this controller
.controller('cntrl',function($scope,appfactory,$http){

  $scope.data=[];
  appfactory.setValue('test abc');

  $scope.getData=function(){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
      $scope.data=data;
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    })
  }
  $scope.getData();
  $scope.toggle=function(){
      if(appfactory.mode()=='a'){
    $scope.message='naveen'
  }else {
     if(appfactory.mode()=='b'){
       $scope.message='parveen'
  }
  }
  }

})
```

if i comment out this line  **$scope.getData();**  or remove this line  **$scope.getData();** then my test is pass and I am able to remove this error .
My Question why this error occurred?  If am not able to use the function in controller then what is the use of testing of this function ?

Answer (score 0):

When initialising the controller because you're calling `$scope.getData()`, `data.json` will be fetched. So, when initialising the controller in test, that request would have to be mocked every time controller is initialised.

One way to overcome this is to add `ng-init="getData()"` to the html element using this controller, so that the data would be fetched but only on request by the html and not when controller is initialized.