# How to call $http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to make a demo of $http request and test that service also..I do like this

```
.controller('cntrl',function($scope,appfactory,$http){

  $scope.data=[];
  appfactory.setValue('test abc');

  $scope.getData=function(){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
      $scope.data=data;
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    })
  }
  $scope.getData();
  $scope.toggle=function(){
      if(appfactory.mode()=='a'){
    $scope.message='naveen'
  }else {
     if(appfactory.mode()=='b'){
       $scope.message='parveen'
  }
  }
  }

})
```

I load that data from json file and display it on view..But when I try to test that application ..I got error why ? how to remove that error

```
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller,appfactory,_$httpBackend_) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();  
    $httpBackend=_$httpBackend_;

      createController = function() {
       return $controller('cntrl', {'$scope' : $scope });
     };

}));



   it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    var response=[{"name":"naveen"},{"name":"parveen"}]
    $httpBackend.expectGET('data.json').respond(response);
         var controller = createController();

     $scope.getData();
     $httpBackend.flush();

     expect($scope.data[0].name).toEqual('naveen')
  });


})
```

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/zdfYdtWbnQz22nEbl6V8?p=preview

Comment: @claies my problem is different..!!

Comment: how is it different? you never supply a `whenGET` in this code.

Comment: ohh got it..!!solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http call to get data is effectively getting called twice in the test. One is when the controller is initialized (because you're calling `$scope.getData()`) and the second is when you manually call `$scope.getData()` in the spec.

And your expectation is only mocked once (before controller initialisation). To fix the test (to mimic what the controller is *actually* doing), the expectation has to be set once more before `$scope.getData()` is called.

See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eLPOZTCgkSfoACLJsVZo?p=preview

OR

You can replace the `expectGET` with `whenGET` which doesn't fail the test if the resource is not called. BUT since you're expecting `expect($scope.data[0].name).toEqual('naveen')` where 'naveen' comes from the http respose, that change should be fine.

Comment: P.S. Is this post related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562051/how-to-remove-unexpected-request-get-data-json